# React/Redux store state is not saved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I use thunk middleware and pass initial state to React, but the problem is that React state is not saved when I visit other links.
After successfully logged in, it's supposed to render dashboard.
User must be redirected to dashboard(which is the root path, `/`) when he tries to go to `/login` page.

Should i use redux-router too?

I omitted some of code, but it almost looks like below.

**init.js**
*I passed store to Provider*

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  const isLoggedIn = store.getState().auth.isLoggedIn;
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    });
  }
}

<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path='/' component={App} store={store}>
        <IndexRoute
          components={{
            main: MainServices,
            aside: Aside
          }}
          onEnter={requireAuth}
          />
        <Route
          path="login"
          components={{
            login: Login
          }}
          />
         ...
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import initialState from './initialState';

const store = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);

export default function () {
  return store(rootReducer, initialState);
}
```

**initialState.js**

```
var initialState = {
  auth: {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    isLoggingIn: false,
    response: null,
  },
};

export default initialState;
```

**App.jsx**
*Initial App's state passed down to React's `props`*

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Login from './Login';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='appWrapper height'>
        {
          this.props.auth.isLoggedIn ?
          <Dashboard {...this.props} /> : <Login {...this.props} />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


let mapStateToProps = function(appState) {
  return {
    auth: appState.auth,
  };
};

let mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
    logoutRequest: function() {
      console.log("logoutRequest dispatched!");
    }
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**Login.jsx**

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(`componentWillMount in login`);
    if (this.props.auth.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log(`you already logged in..!`);
      browserHistory.push('/');
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-outer">
        <Grid className="login-inner">
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <LoginHeader />
              <LoginContainer />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**LoginContainer.jsx**

```
export default class LoginContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-container">
        <div className="outer">
          <div className="inner">
            <LoginTitle />
            <div className="login-box">
              <h2>Sign in</h2>
              <LoginInput />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**LoginInput.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Input, ButtonToolbar, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { spring } from 'react-motion';
import Transition from 'react-motion-ui-pack';
import Loader from 'react-loader';
import * as actions from '../../actions/loginActions';

class LoginInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      idText: '',
      passText: '',
      idShow: false,
      passShow: false,
      loaded: true
    };

    this.handleIdChange = this.handleIdChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePassChange = this.handlePassChange.bind(this);
    this.loginRequest = this.loginRequest.bind(this);
  }

  handleIdChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      idText: e.target.value
    });

    if (e.target.value != '') {
      this.setState({
        idShow: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        idShow: false
      });
    }
  }

  handlePassChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      passText: e.target.value
    });

    if (e.target.value != '') {
      this.setState({
        passShow: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        passShow: false
      });
    }
  }

  loginRequest(e) {

    this.setState({loaded: false});

    if (!this.state.idText || !this.state.passText) {
      this.setState({loaded: true});
    }

    if (this.state.idText && this.state.passText) {
      this.setState({
        loaded: false,
        idText: this.state.idText,
        passText: this.state.passText,
      });
      this.props.login(this.state.idText, this.state.passText);
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  }

   render() {
    return (
      <form className="loginForm">
        <div className="form-group input-login id">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              ref="idText"
              placeholder="ID"
              value={this.state.idText}
              onChange={this.handleIdChange}
            />
          <Transition
            component={false}
            enter={{
              opacity: 1
            }}
            leave={{
              opacity: 0
            }}
          >
            {
              this.state.idShow &&
              <label
                htmlFor=""
                className="control-label"
              >
                ID
              </label>
            }
          </Transition>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group input-login password">
          <input
            type="password"
            className="form-control"
            ref="passText"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={this.state.passText}
            onChange={this.handlePassChange}
          />
          <Transition
            component={false}
            enter={{
              opacity: 1
            }}
            leave={{
              opacity: 0
            }}
          >
            {
              this.state.passShow &&
              <label
                htmlFor=""
                className="control-label"
              >
                Password
              </label>
            }
          </Transition>
        </div>
        <Input
          type="checkbox"
          groupClassName="checkbox-login"
          label="Keep me signed in"
        />
        <ButtonToolbar>
          <Button
            href="#"
            onClick={this.loginRequest}
          >
            <div
              className="sign-arrow"
              hidden={!this.state.loaded}
            >
              <h6>
                ENTER
              </h6>
              <img src="images/ic-right-arrow-2.svg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <Loader
              className="spinner"
              loaded={this.state.loaded}
              lines={10}
              length={3}
              width={2}
              radius={4}
              corners={1}
              rotate={0}
              direction={1}
              color="#fff"
              speed={1.5}
              trail={60}
              shadow={false}
              hwaccel={false}
              scale={1}
            />
          </Button>
        </ButtonToolbar>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

let mapStateToProps = function(appState) {
  return {
    auth: appState.auth,
  };
};

let mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
          login: function(id, pwd) {
            dispatch(actions.login(id, pwd));
          }
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LoginInput);
```

**loginActions.js**

```
export function loginFailure(error) {
  return { error, type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE };
}

export function loginSuccess(response) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ response, type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS });
    browserHistory.push('/');
  };
}

export function loginRequest(id, pwd) {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST,
    command: 'login',
    lang: 'en',
    str: encodeCredentials(id, pwd),
    ip: '',
    device_id: '',
    install_ver: '',
  };
}

export function login(id, pwd) {
  const credentials = loginRequest(id, pwd);

  return dispatch => {
    fetchJSON(`${API.ROOT_PATH}${API.END_POINT.LOGIN}`, {
      method: 'post',
      body: credentials,
    }).then(data => {
      dispatch(loginSuccess(data));
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(`request failed ${error}`);
    });
  };

}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import authReducer from './authReducer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**authReducer.js**

```
import initialState from '../store/initialState';
import * as ActionTypes from '../actionTypes/authActionTypes';

const authReducer = function authReducer(state = initialState.auth, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoggingIn: true,
        isLoggedIn: false,
      });
    case ActionTypes.LOGOUT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        isLoggingIn: false,
      });
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        error: action.error,
        isLoggingIn: false,
        isLoggedIn: false,
      });
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoggedIn: true,
        isLoggingIn: false,
        response: action.response,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way how your store can be saved between two different http requests. The only approach for that is not reloading page itself, but you can emulate for user that page was reloaded when user clicks the link by manipulation with history API which is native object in all modern browsers. BUT best approach is to take [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) which will take care about everything you need in your react App, and if you want to keep state of the router in your redux store you can use [redux-simple-router](https://github.com/rackt/redux-simple-router).

Comment: I solved it with using `redux-save-state` which is this package stores the app state in LocalStorage. Is it okay to keep this way? https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-save-state

Comment: @seoyoochan It depends on what you need. From my point of view you can simply make a SPA (Single Page Application) with SSR (Server side rendering). Take a look at this example - https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/. Be aware they are using redux-router which is experimental, they have plans to migrate their example to redux-simple-router.

Comment: because of the upgraded `history` package, redux-router has some problems. I already tried it last night for hours and its learning curve was steep. But i will try redux-simple-router. Then i guess i should not redirect unlogged-in user to login page. Instead, i change the look of page and the url? so that i don't request another http?

Comment: Right, you fetch necessary data from the server (with any ajax client you like, e.g. superagent, isomorphic-fetch, etc) then tell react router make a transition. It will change url in the browser by itself and render appropriate component with fetched data without page reloading.

Comment: redux-router !== react-router. redux-router and redux-simple-router are BOTH based on react-router. So, you need react-router anyway. Just to make it clear in case you misunderstood that part.