# State seems to revert to default each time a component renders

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm working on a React/Redux/Thunk/React Router application and it appears that state is unexpectedly reverting to the default state for each reducer each time a component renders.

For example:

I browse to the Homepage route, render the Homepage component, and state is correctly set - The new state shows as expected in the output from loggerMiddleware and the application works as expected.

However, when I then browse to another route and render an EventPage component, it's as if state is empty/default - the `state` argument in mapStateToProps is simply a list of empty objects, as if I'm seeing the default output from combinereducers. I see the same thing in the loggerMiddleware output. Similarly, when I browse back to the homepage component, state is once again empty/default.

My expectation is that state would remain between page views/component renders. Is that correct?

Some excerpts of the application in question in case it's helpful in identifying any mistakes I'm making - Happy to provide more as well:

The bottom of the Eventpage and Homepage components/containers:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EventPage);
```

The router as defined in index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}  >
            <Route path="/" component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path="EventsSimpleList" component={EventsSimpleList}/>
            <Route path="events/:eventId" component={EventPage}/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('#root'));
```

My rootReducer definition:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  EventsToAssets: EventsToAssetsReducer,
  Assets: AssetsReducer,
  Events: EventsReducer,
  Venues: VenuesReducer,
  Artists: ArtistsReducer,
  Homepage: HomepageReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Your expectation is correct, we're gonna need to see more code. Maybe you're calling `createStore` more than once? or even ReactDom.render more than once? maybe modifying state in reducer?

Comment: @azium, I found an answer on another question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34813184/479891 which says that "There is no way how your store can be saved between two different http requests." If I understand correctly, this seems to conflict with your comment that my expectation is correct that "state would remain between page views/component renders". Perhaps the behavior I'm observing in this question is to be expected?

Comment: That answer specifically says the fix is use React Router, which is what you're doing. When using a client side router, you don't reload the JavaScript that builds your store, so it would persist across routes. The problem is elsewhere in your code. How are you serving the app? Through webpack dev server or express? Does this happen in both dev and prod?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - This is my first React project and the explanation is helpful! I'm serving through webpack-dev-server locally and express in production and the behavior is the same in both places. I can say that state appeared to be preserved/accessible between components as expected before I did some recent refactoring: I added several components and reducers, so it's tough to isolate a specific change. I can say that even in the reducers, the `state` argument is empty so the problem may not be specific to connected containers.

Comment: One more bit of context: As part of the aforementioned refactoring, I removed a component that previously did a `  this.setState({data: data});` inside of componentDidMount(), which may account for why state was successfully set previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by replacing `<a>` elements with `<Link>` elements as imported from react-router. This doesn't solve the problem in the case that a user manually enters a new URL into their address bar, but does solve the problem in the case of links. I believe that is actually expected behavior. I am confident that someone will correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Ahh yeah makes sense. You can fix the manually entered url problem by using localstorage (if you need to support that). If you do, take a look at the redux-persist library.